# Building an expanding grid with VueJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

Currently, I'm working on an data (f.g. images) overview.

And I want the content to expand when clicked (like the Google images overview for example). Toggling the expanding works flawless (show = !show), but unfortunately, I couldn't find any way to open just the clicked item.. so all items expand or shrink together.

I read about selected states (https://alligator.io/vuejs/dynamic-styles/ - binding styles dynamically).. but couldn't get this to work with my solution.

Here is my approach: https://jsfiddle.net/chrtz/fw5r8a5k/2/

**HTML:**

```
    <div id="app">
    <div class="item" v-for="i in 100">
      <div class="thumb" @click="show = !show">
        Item #{{ i }}
      </div>
      <div v-show="show"  class="detail">
        <button id="close" @click="show = !show">
        X  
        </button>
        <h1>Item {{ i }}'s details'</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**JS:**

```
  new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      show: false
    }
  })
```

Maybe one of you might know a solution.
And just like Phunky's example (below), how can I add the space between the rows, when the content expands, dynamically? I tried somethings with Phunky's code but couldn't get it to work.

(this was my inspiration: https://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/03/19/thumbnail-grid-with-expanding-preview/

and an old archived Vue forum post:
https://forum-archive.vuejs.org/topic/2108/architecture-design-question/2

*Phunky* did a good solution based on VueJs1.0:
https://jsfiddle.net/Phunky/caa62nL0/ 
(I tried to add a close button there, but this didn't worked with out adding tons of additional JavaScript! And I couldn't find a method to unselect an item.)

Additionally, the topic owner (*monk*) was right, loading the content dynamically would be the best solution.. does anyone have an idea here, too?)

Thanks a lot.

PS: for sure, I'm still new o VueJS

Comment: Rather than having a boolean control whether everyone's show state is open, have `show` indicate which `i` is open, and use `vshow="show == i"`.

Comment: WOW. this just works. and it was so damn simple! Thank you!

Now, I just have to figure out how to push the other items downwards, when details expand.

Comment: We try to keep things simple here in Vue. We figure if you want complicated you'll use Angular. ;)